# Google cloud functions in python to read firebase realtime data

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a simple Google Cloud Function to learn, with the new Python3.7 option, and I would like to read/write some data to Firebase Realtime db.

I found some information to use Firestore that worked, but now I need to use the realtime Database.

```
# global
import firebase_admin

from firebase_admin import db
# from firebase_admin import firestore

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

def check_prices_updates(request):
"""Responds to any HTTP request.
Args:
    request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
Returns:
    The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
    Response object using
    make_response 
"""

collection = 'pricelist'
mybase = db.reference(collection)

   ....[other code]

return "OK"
```

This is an excerpt of my code, the documentation says that the `initialize_app()` must be left empty to collect the project default credentials.

The line where I call db.reference(collection) give me the exception:

> ValueError: Invalid databaseURL option: "None". databaseURL must be a non-empty URL string.

as if the configuration parameters did not show the requested key 'databaseURL'. With Firestore, as example I could call `firestore.client()`, after the import from firebase_admin, adding 'google-cloud-firestore in requirements.txt.

Now, for firebase, what should I fix to read and write on the db?

PS. on my db the ".read" rule is true for all so I haven't trouble on auth!

**UPDATE:**
After a good sleep I realized that to access the realtime db I need to pass some options to initialize_app, as follow:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(options={'databaseURL': 'https://[PROJECT-NAME].firebaseio.com'})
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

#### Initiliase the Firebase Admin SDK

- This will access the db, even if you put permission restrictions on read, write, as your python will have admin access
- If you have multiple database instance (Only available for blaze plan)
- Initilise them with different app name inside single python script

```py
#Firebase Admin Imports
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

#Firebase admin sdk Key - Save it as secret
firebaseval={
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<project_id>",
  "private_key_id": "<private_key>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-ipcf5@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<clinet_id>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-ipcf5%40<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

cred = credentials.Certificate(firebaseval)

print("\n---------------------------")
print("Initialising Firebase...")

#Initilising Database 1- fetching stock and option details
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://<project_id>-<instance_id1>.firebaseio.com/'
})

# Initilising Database 2- Different instance ID
app2 = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://<project_id>-<instance_id2>..firebaseio.com/'
}, name='app2')

# Initilising Database 3- Different instance ID
app3 = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://<project_id>-<instance_id3>..firebaseio.com/'
}, name='app3')

print("Initialised Firebase")
print("---------------------------\n")
```

#### Accessing the different database Instances

```py
# database instance_id2
mainref2=db.reference("PATH",app2)  

# database instance_id3
mainref3==db.reference("PATH",app3)


# Reading whole data from 
mainref2.get()

# Reading inside child node from db instance_id2
mainref2.child("child_name").get()

# Setting json data to db instance_id3
mainref3.set({"data":"something"})
```